# C# write data in next column special character

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, c#-4.0

I am writing the data from sql table and exporting to the excel file but problem is coming is data is coming in only one cell with `\` symbol between all the data. which special character i should use to move to the next column

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
using (System.IO.StreamWriter fs1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Filename))
{
     // Loop through the fields and add headers
     for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
     {
         string name = dr.GetName(i);
         if (name.Contains(","))
            name = "\"" + name + "\"";

         fs1.Write(name + "\\");

     }
     fs1.WriteLine();

     // Loop through the rows and output the data
     while (dr.Read())
     {
          for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
          {
               string value = dr[i].ToString();
               if (value.Contains(","))
                    value = "\"" + value + "\"";

               fs1.Write(value + "\\");                            
          }
          fs1.WriteLine();
     }
     fs1.Close();
}
```

**output**
a\b\c\d
in the one column.. I want a b c d in next to each other columns

Comment: It's hard to follow your question, please post an example of a line of data from the file

Comment: if it's using `\` as a delimeter, try `\\` ? Not sure what's the problem or what you're asking

Comment: @3dd its output is coming in one column.. not in next to each other columns.. please check output

Comment: @Noctis \ I am already trying

Answer (score 0):

For example your text file contains following data:

```
a\b\c\d
1\2\3\4
```

You can read this file in excel and specify delimiter symbol:

Go to Microsoft Excel (I am using 2010 version). 
File > Open > Select Filter `Text Files`
Pick the the file.

You will see following dialogs:

[image]

[image]

Move on and select a Type of the column and finish the text import wizard.

Output will be as required.

**Using Code**:

Change backslash delimiter `\\` with `,`

```
 fs1.Write(name + ",");
```

Save the file with `.csv` extension.

Comment: yes write... isnt possible to create excel formatted file

Comment: Possible by `using Microsoft.Excel.InterOp` assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is not going to automatically split when you open a file delimited by "\". If you want it to recognize them as separate columns you either need a csv or a txt document (comma delimited and tab delimited respectively.

Either export to a .csv file with:

```
fs1.Write(value + ",");
```

Or to a .txt file with

```
fs1.Write(value + "\t");
```

Not sure if you care but the way you have it written now you will have a delimiter on the end of each row in the output file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can directly write the data to an excel file using datatable in different ways 
Check
http://www.dotnetgallery.com/lab/resource44-Export-to-excel-from-DataTable-using-CNET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This might not be for your original question, but I believe this is what you need.

Do you know that you can output the result as Excel.

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\yourExcel.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'"))
{
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE [Sheet1] ([Column1] string,
                 [Column2] string, [Column3] string, [Column4] string)",
                 conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert Into [Sheet1] Values ('a','b','c','d')", conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is.

Following code works for me:

```
var input = @"a\b\c\d";
var list = new List<string>();

foreach (var piece in input.Split('\\'))
{
    list.Add(piece);
}

// list holds 4 strings: "a", "b","c","d"
```

or you can simply replace the offending `\` with something less offensive (`|` for example) by doing :

```
var changed = input.Replace('\\','|');
// changed holds :"a|b|c|d"
```

and then iterate on that.